# Conan packages migration from official repo to local private repo

Tags: c++, artifactory, conan

I would like to know if it is possible to upload a package from official "conan-center" repo and all its dependencies into a local private repository (who does not have internet access)

Example:

In "conan-center" repo there is a package A.
Package A has some dependencies: B and C.

I wanto to upload A (and automatically B and C) in a private artifactory repo using the "conan upload" command.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: There is no out of the box solution as far as I know. Maybe you can use `conan info` command combined with `conan upload`. Also one more solution might be to always have clean conan cache and then upload everything related to the package `A` with `conan upload *`. Maybe someone will come up with better approach - I would be very interested in it too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best to do it is using the Artifactory feature [Remote Repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management), where Artifactory will download it for you when a package is not available in your Local Remote.

However, if you don't have internet connection, it will be more complicated, you will need to download which packages do you need and upload them manually.

For instance, you can use [conan download](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/misc/download.html) command and after that [conan upload](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/uploading_to_remotes.html)

For instance:

```
conan download openssl/1.1.1@ -r conancenter
conan user -p mypassword -r mylocalremote username
conan upload "*" -r mylocalremote --all --confirm --parallel
```

In my opinion you should try to solve the connection limitation, because using Artifactory Remote Repository will save a lot of your time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I need to isolate the machine which contains the conan repository from the official conan-center respository for security reason.
I will try to download packages and then upload the entire cache.

Comment: So probably you can't download binaries too, due security. JFrog also offers X-Ray, which scan your binaries in Artifactory. Anyway, if you can not download binaries and need to build sources, you have to run `conan download --recipe`, so Conan client will download ONLY the recipe, not the binaries.